# insert into mysql else update using select?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help, I'm trying to make this script select the values from my mysql table where appropriate and update them if they exist, and if they don't exist then to insert them instead.

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong thanks.

```
    <?php
        require_once("session.php"); 
        require_once("functions.php");
        require('_config/connection.php');

        session_start();

        include '_config/connection.php'; 

        $height_ft = $_POST['height_ft'];
        $height_in = $_POST['height_in'];
        $weight_st = $_POST['weight_st'];
        $weight_lb = $_POST['weight_lb'];    

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT height_ft FROM ptb_stats WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");

        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT height_in FROM ptb_stats WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");

        $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT weight_st FROM ptb_stats WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");

    $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT weight_lb FROM ptb_stats WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");

    if( !$result ) { 
       echo "The username you entered does not exist"; 
    } else if( $height_ft != mysql_result( $result, 0 ) ) { 
       echo "";    

         $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_stats SET height_ft='$height_ft' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].""); 

         $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_stats SET height_in='$height_in' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].""); 

         $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_stats SET weight_st='$weight_st' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].""); 

         $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_stats SET weight_lb='$weight_lb' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");    

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_stats (user_id, height_ft) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$height_ft.")"); 

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_stats (user_id, height_in) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$height_in.")"); 

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_stats (user_id, weight_st) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$weight_st.")");

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_stats (user_id, weight_lb) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$weight_lb.")");
    }

    if( $sql ) { 
        $_SESSION['edit_done']="<div class=\"infobox-edit-done\"><strong>Thank You -</strong> Your Details were changed.</div>"; 
        header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    } else { 
        $_SESSION['edit_done2']="<div class=\"infobox-edit-done\"><strong>Oooops! -</strong> That didn't work. Try again.</div>"; 
        header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    }  
?>
```

Comment: If you used a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) it would provide a database layer that would make this so easy to do you wouldn't even have to try. What you're doing here is a mess of code that isn't very easy to follow. Remember you can `UPDATE` multiple columns at once just as you can `SELECT` multiple columns worth of data with a single statement. If you don't have any decent examples to work from, a framework will help you considerably by suggesting best practices to start with.

Comment: The reason you don't roll your own PHP from the ground up is because of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) which this short example seems to be littered with. These are extremely dangerous to leave in *any* application available to the general internet and can have severe consequences if they're exploited.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in MySQL for an update or insert using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which may more concisely solve your question.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

For you query would look something like:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_stats (user_id, height_ft) 
VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']).", "
         .mysql_real_escape_string($height_ft).") 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']).");
```

Comment: Please, if you're going to use `mysql_query` in an answer, always escape the data inserted with `mysql_real_escape_string`. You've also mangled your quoting somehow and got it all confused.